# How to automatically fill download popup in firefox in Python

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

I wrote code to run through a website and download a csv on firefox. Everything works. After you click download the firefox download popup comes up. I need to automatically have it filled in and send the file to a specific path.

I tried some of the methods that I saw on overstack but they didn't work

```
import pytest
import time
import json
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys




# Open a browser and log in

#browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path =r"C:\Users\")
driver.get("website")
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element(By.NAME, "username").click()
driver.find_element(By.NAME, "username").send_keys("")
driver.find_element(By.NAME, "password").click()
driver.find_element(By.NAME, "password").send_keys("")
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span:nth-child(1) > span:nth-child(1)").click()
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".tb-text-box-input").send_keys("integrated systems & automation")
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".tb-text-box-input").send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
#driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".tb-react-dg-brow:nth-child(3) .shared-widgets-datagrid_bcell-wrapper_f18a59jp").click()
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "").click()
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "").click()
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "Site Details").click()
time.sleep(20)
driver.switch_to.frame(1)
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".tab-clip").click()
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".tab-tvTLSpacer > img").click()
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".tab-icon-download").click()
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".tab-downloadDialog > div:nth-child(4)").click()
time.sleep(30)
driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "Download").click()



# Code to auto fill firefox login here.....
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with XPath? Is basic the same, open the DevTools and look for the space for put the user and pass:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='search-bar']/button").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='exports']/form[1]/input[15]").click()
```

I had hard times with PythonSelenium, but xpath solves a lot of problems, if you can send me the site who you are try to login I can help.

Edit1: So, I read your question better, I it's a popup, this can not work, so other thing you can try is use Handler, to change the page, I had a problem, when i click in a button, create a new page popup, and I had to use Handler:

```
iframeSAP = driver.find_element_by_id('ITSFRAME1')
driver.switch_to.frame(iframeSAP)
```

So, iframeSAP is the name of the second page or popup, when create is like a second layer of the site, the selenium never recognize withou you say it the name of the layer, in this case 'ITSFRAME1', the driver.switch_to.frame(), change the page for the new frame, in this case, the popup.